# Avoid findall overflow with n-fractions problem

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp, prolog-findall

I am trying to print all solutions of the [n-fractions problem](http://www.csplib.org/Problems/prob041/) for n=4:

```
:- lib(ic).

fractions(Digits) :-
   Digits = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L],

   Digits #:: 1..9,

   ic:alldifferent(Digits),

   X #= 10*B+C,
   Y #= 10*E+F,
   Z #= 10*H+I,
   V #= 10*K+L,

   A*Y*Z*V + D*X*Z*V + G*X*Y*V + J*X*Y*Z #= X*Y*Z*V,

   A*Y #=< D*X,
   D*Z #=< G*Y,
   G*V #=< J*Z,

   search(Digits,0,input_order,indomain,complete,[]).
```

When I run the query:

```
?- findall(Digits,fractions(Digits),List).
```

I get the following exception:

```
*** Overflow of the local/control stack!
You can use the "-l kBytes" (LOCALSIZE) option to have a larger stack.
Peak sizes were: local stack 105728 kbytes, control stack 25344 kbytes
```

I am thinking if there is a way to loop inside the program and print one solution each time, or I can't do that because the problem has too many solutions?

Comment: Of interest: eclipseclp [library(ic)](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/index.html)

Comment: Try `fractions(Digits), false` first. If this terminates, then you have too many solutions. Why do you want to have all these solutions in a list?

Comment: What is `ic:alldifferent/2`? Shouldn't the second argument be ground?

Comment: The code you posted does not produce any exception. It produces `List=[]` because `fractions(Digits)` fails (as explained by damianodamiano). Your problem must lie elsewhere. Once you fixed that, you can print all solutions using a query like `?- fractions(Digits), writeln(Digits), fail.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, your code fails because the `alldifferent(Digits)` constraint is too restrictive.  The digits must be allowed to occur between 1 and 2 times.  In [eclipse-clp](/questions/tagged/eclipse-clp), you can use constraints such as [atleast/3](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic_global/atleast-3.html), [atmost/3](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic_global/atmost-3.html), [occurrences/3](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic_global/occurrences-3.html) or [gcc/2](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib_public/ic_global_gac/gcc-2.html) to express this.

Slightly off-topic: as you are using ECLiPSe's [ic-solver](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/index.html) (which can handle continuous domains), you can actually use a model much closer to the [original specification](http://www.csplib.org/Problems/prob041/), without introducing lots of multiplications:

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(ic_global).

fractions4(Digits) :-

    Digits = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L],
    Digits #:: 1..9,

    A/(10*B+C) + D/(10*E+F) + G/(10*H+I) + J/(10*K+L) $= 1,

    ( for(I,1,9), param(Digits) do
        occurrences(I, Digits, NOcc), NOcc #:: 1..2
    ),

    lex_le([A,B,C], [D,E,F]),       % lex-ordering to eliminate symmetry
    lex_le([D,E,F], [G,H,I]),
    lex_le([G,H,I], [J,K,L]),

    labeling(Digits).
```

Apart from the main equality constraint (using `$=` instead of `#=` because we don't want to require integrality here), I've used [occurrences/3](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic_global/occurrences-3.html) for the occurrence restrictions, and [lexicographic ordering](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic_global/lex_le-2.html) constraints as a more standard way of eliminating symmetry. Result:

```
?- findall(Ds, fractions4(Ds), Dss), length(Dss, NSol).
Dss = [[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 1, 4, 9, 2, 7], [1, 2, 6, 5, 3, 9, 7, 1, 4, 8, 2, 4], [1, 2, 6, 5, 3, 9, 7, 8, 4, 9, 1, 2], [1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 9, 8, 1, 3, 9, 5, 4], [1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 5, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 8, 1, 7, 8, 5, 2, 9, 2, ...], [1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 7, 1, 4, 9, ...], [1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 8, ...], [1, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, ...], [1, 3, 6, 5, 4, 5, 8, ...], [1, 3, 6, 5, 6, 3, ...], [1, 3, 6, 6, 5, ...], [1, 3, 6, 7, ...], [1, 3, 9, ...], [1, 3, ...], [1, ...], [...], ...]
NSol = 1384
Yes (82.66s cpu)
```

An added advantage of this model is that it can be quite easily turned into a [generic model for arbitrary N](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/nfractions.ecl.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Simply your predicate fails. If you remove all the constraints except `alldifferent/1` and `search/6` (just to understand the problem) and call `?- fractions(Digits).` you get `false` because it's impossible to have a list with 12 elements (`Digits = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L]`) with domain for each element `Digits #:: 1..9` and constraint those elements to be all different (`ic:alldifferent(Digits)`). 9 options for 12 elements: unsolvable. If you expand the domain up to 12 (`Digits #:: 1..12`), you get a solution:

```
?- fractions(Digits).
Digits = [2, 3, 4, 9, 7, 10, 12, 8, 5, 11, 1, 6]
Yes (94.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
```

Then you can apply `findall/3` and see other solutions...

Comment: While your statements are technically correct (and I don't have anything against polydactyly), your answer is "solving" the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

Many [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) implementations offer `global_cardinality` constraints which I use in this example. In the following I use SICStus Prolog 4.5.0:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

fractions(Digits) :-
   Digits = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L],
   domain(Digits, 1, 9),
   global_cardinality(Digits, [1-N1,2-N2,3-N3,4-N4,5-N5,6-N6,7-N7,8-N8,9-N9]),
   domain([N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9], 1, 2),
   X #= 10*B+C,
   Y #= 10*E+F,
   Z #= 10*H+I,
   V #= 10*K+L,
   Z*V #= ZV,
   X*Y #= XY,
   A*Y*ZV + D*X*ZV + G*XY*V + J*XY*Z #= XY*ZV,
   X #=< Y, X #= Y #=> A #=< D,                   % break some symmetries
   Y #=< Z, Y #= Z #=> D #=< G,
   Z #=< V, Z #= V #=> G #=< J.
```

Sample use:

```
| ?- n_fractions(4,Zs), labeling([enum],Zs).
Zs = [2,1,2,9,1,8,7,3,5,6,4,5] ? ;
Zs = [2,1,3,7,1,8,9,2,6,5,4,5] ? ;
Zs = [2,1,3,7,1,8,9,2,6,6,5,4] ? ;
...
no
```

Using [prolog-findall](/questions/tagged/prolog-findall) for collecting all solutions works out all right, too:

```
?- findall(Zs,(n _fractions(4,Zs), labeling([enum],Zs)), Zss),
   length(Zss, N_sols).
Zss = [[2,1,2,9,1,8,7,3,5|...],
       [2,1,3,7,1,8,9,2,6|...],
       [2,1,3,7,1,8,9,2|...],
       [2,1,3,8,1,5,7|...],
       [2,1,3,8,1,6|...],
       [2,1,3,9,1|...],
       [2,1,3,9|...],
       [2,1,4|...],
       [2,1|...],
       [...|...]|...],
N_sols = 1384 ? ;
no
```

Comment: What is the speed benefit of nvalue? I find it documented here: http://www.lirmm.fr/~bessiere/stock/cpaior06.pdf

Comment: @j4nbur53. Not much (something like 5-10%). The fastest variant uses `global_cardinality/3` like so: instead of the `nvalue(9,Digits)` use `global_cardinality(Digits, [1-N1,2-N2,3-N3,4-N4,5-N5,6-N6,7-N7,8-N8,9-N9], [consistency(value)]), domain([N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9],1,sup)`.

Comment: nvalue is the wrong constraint here. According to the specification, the digits must occur between 1 and 2 times.

Comment: @jschimpf. I agree up to a point. The "simple generalisation" fails to cover the case `N=2`... But `global_cardinality/2` it is!